# Как в методе вывести переменную из цикла?

Tags: python, циклы, методы

Как вернуть `op` в `func1` без остановки цикла?
(Методы будут работать одновременно)

```py
def func0():
    op=0
    for _ in range(128_000_000):
        op+=1

def func1():
    print(op)#???
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "будут работать одновременно"? От этого и ответ будет зависеть.

Answer (score 4):

```
def func0():
    op=0
    for _ in range(128):
        op+=1
        yield op


def func1():
    for i in func0():
        print(i)


func1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак, вроде нужно сделать 1 функцию, иначе никак

```
def func0():
    op=0
    for _ in range(128_000_000):
        op+=1
        print(op)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).